# How to upload excel file to import `question_bank` in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I have the entire question list saved in Microsoft excel spreadsheet. I would like to import this file to question bank in Moodle.

How to upload excel file to import question bank in Moodle ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle doesn't allow to Excel Import Question, you import question only this format:

Aiken format
Blackboard
Blackboard V6+
Embedded answers (Cloze)
Examview
GIFT format
Learnwise format
Missing word format
Moodle XML format
WebCT format

The best way to import question using xml format, or still you want to use excel, then you have need to customize xls format in Moodle..